# Computably enumerable sets are not algorithmically random

Tags: logic, computability, algorithmic-randomness

I am informed that no computably enumerable sets are algorithmically random.  I tried to show it by constructing an ML test,  and looked up the proof in Downey & Hirschfeldt, but in vain.  I would like know an elementary proof for the fact.

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Comment: Can you explain what definition of "algorithmically random" do you use ? Because there are several possible definitions.

Comment: @Xoff I mean Martin-Loef random.

Comment: If you like the martingale definition of random, then it's easy to see: just bet on the bits you know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be a recursive enumerable set.

- if $S$ is finite, it can't be random
- if $S$ is infinite, by definition of "recursive enumerable" there is an injective total program $p: \mathbb N\rightarrow S$. You can use $p$ to build your constructive null cover. Let $s(i)=\max_{k\le i}p(k)$. Consider the set of finite binary words $W_i$ such that $$W_i=\{w\;|\; (\forall k\le i :w_{p(k)}=1)\wedge(|w|=s(i))\}$$
  and let $U_i$ a sequence of open sets such that ($C_w$ is the cylinder defined by $w$)
  $$U_i=\bigcup_{w\in W_i}C_{w}$$

Then $U_i$ defines a  constructive null cover that contains $S$.

Comment: Isn't it the case that according to what you write $U_i = [1^i]$, where $[w] = C_w$, assuming by $w_k$ you mean the $k$-th character of $w$?

Comment: Sorry, This is $p(k)$ of course !