# Non-computable c.e. sets are Kurtz random

Tags: logic, computability, algorithmic-randomness

I'm trying to directly show that non-computable c.e. sets are Kurtz random, without using the concept of genericity, but to little success.  I assume by way of contradiction that $\emptyset'$  (for example) is not included in some c.e. class $W \subset 2^\omega$ whose measure is 1.  However, I have no idea how I can exploit the condition about the measure.

Is it easy to see the proposition directly? If so, I'd be grateful if you can provide me with a clue.  (If not, I'm happy with the proof via genericity.)

Comment: Are you sure about this? (Please cite your source.)

Comment: @QuinnCulver Thank you for your interest.  Downey & Hirschfeldt say that, in Proposition 2.24.2, every noncomputable c.e. set computes a 1-generic
set.  Then, 1-generic sets are weakly 1-generic, and by Theorem 8.11.7, they are Kurtz random.

Comment: So the statement should be that every non-computable c.e. set *computes* a Kurtz random.

Comment: @QuinnCulver What does it mean for every non-computable c.e. set _computes_ a Kurtz random?  I've thought _computes_ mean _is_.

Comment: No, $A$ computes $B$, written $B \leq_{T} A$ if there's a Turing functional $\Phi_{e}$ such that $\Phi_{e}^{A}=B$. Certainly $A \leq_{T} A$, but just because $B \leq_{T} A$ doesn't mean $B=A$. For example $\emptyset \leq_{T} \{0,2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$. However, maybe what you're thinking is that if $A\leq_{T} B$ and $B\leq_{T}A$ then $A$ and $B$ are Turing equivalent (i.e. this is an equivalence relation).

Comment: @QuinnCulver is the term _compute_ defined in D & H, if you have a copy? (I've thought not.)

Comment: It's defined in section 2.4.1.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Turing reduction is defined there, but to my best knowledge it's not defined for $A$ to compute $B$ there, where $A$ and $B$ are sets.  Is the usage of the word  in the sense you mentioned as a verb common in computability?

Comment: They do define, in that section, $B$-computable and computable in $B$. Yes, the usage of 'compute' in the sense I mentioned is standard.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Thank you for teaching me.  As you said I should accept the definition for $B$-computability for the definition of the verb _compute_. (The definition's unhelpful for novices like me, though.  When I first saw the proposition, I looked up _compute_ in the index and didn't find it, concluding  that it is used in an informal way and that _computes_ means _is_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No c.e. set is Kurtz random because any infinite c.e. set has an infinite computable subset and then a test consisting of clopen sets can easily be built to zoom in on that infinite computable subset. I'll provide more details if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, [the answer to my previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/634571/20552) showed the assertion.